# autoresizingmask not working properly in xcode6

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode6.1, iphone-6, autoresizingmask

I am implementing a tableviewcell with width of 320. I added a uilabel and apply autoresizing mask to snap the label to right edge of the screen. But when  i run it in iPhone 6, the label going out of window(x value 546). any idea why this is happening? I tried to add a container view and put the label in it. container view is resizing correctly to 375pix width. But the label still out of window

Comment: Post some screenshots.

Comment: did you do this?
[uilabel setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin];